# limit of a quite complex function when a parameter tends to + Infinity

Tags: limits

For the purpose of CG and animation, I'm looking for a function thats tends to 1 when x tends to +Infinity, and have a tangent of 1 when x = 0.

I found that function:

$f\left(x\right)=2\frac{\left(\frac{2x}{p}+1\right)^{p}}{\left(\frac{2x}{p}+1\right)^{p}+1}-1$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/crvuqwq0qc?lang=fr

[image: limit function]

Which is cool. The derivative is indeed 1 at x = zero.
And I can control the speed at which the function tends to 1 by increasing p.

But, then, i noted that when p is big, say bigger than 50, the function seems not to evolve anymore. Clearly, there is a limit when p goes big.

Question 1:
How to name that?
It's not the limit of the function (which is 1, whatever p could be), it's the limit of the shape of the function, of its evolution.

Question 2:
Could we find that "limit function"?
Could we write a function that no longer involves p, but somehow assumes that p = +Infinity?

NB: Please excuse my guesswork, I'm not a mathematician, but happy to use a little math every now and then.

Comment: That's gonna be 2\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}-1 (I think you can copy and paste into desmos)

Comment: For large $p$, $\left(\frac{2x}p+1\right)^p\approx e^{2x}$.

Comment: @Moisés That's true! I read on Wikipedia that $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}$ has a limit of $e$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$y=\left(\frac{2 x}{p}+1\right)^p_\implies \log(y)=p \log\left(1+\frac{2 x}{p}\right)$$ Using Taylor series
$$\log(y)=p\Bigg[\frac{2 x}{p}-\frac{2 x^2}{p^2}+\frac{8 x^3}{3 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right) \Bigg]=2 x-\frac{2 x^2}{p}+\frac{8 x^3}{3 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e^{2x}\Bigg[1-\frac{2 x^2}{p}+\frac{2 x^3 (3 x+4)}{3 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)\Bigg]$$
$$\frac y {y+1}=\frac{1}{2} (\tanh (x)+1)-\frac{x^2 \text{sech}^2(x)}{2 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$
$$f(x)=2 \frac y {y+1}-1=\tanh (x)-\frac{x^2 \text{sech}^2(x)}{p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$

You can control even more if you change the $2$ by $a$ and you could have
$$f(x)=\tanh \left(\frac{a x}{2}\right)-\frac{a^2 x^2 \text{sech}^2\left(\frac{a x}{2}\right)}{4 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$

Comment: thx for the answer... which I do not know what to do, because too complicated for me. I'm currently reading about the Big O notation (that i've only seen in computer science about algorithm... until today).

Answer (score 1):

Given that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}
\right)^x=e,
$$
We can take
$$
\lim_{p\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{2x}{p}
\right)^p = 
\lim_{p\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{p}{2x}\right)}
\right)^{\frac{p}{2x}\cdot 2x} = 
\lim_{p\to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{p}{2x}\right)}
\right)^{\frac{p}{2x}}\right)^{2x} ,
$$
Now we can just rename $a = \frac{p}{2x}$. If $x>0$, then $a\to \infty$ as $p\to \infty$, so
$$
\lim_{p\to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{p}{2x}\right)}
\right)^{\frac{p}{2x}}\right)^{2x}=
\lim_{a\to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{a}
\right)^{a}\right)^{2x},
$$
since the power function with exponent $2x$ is continuous,
$$
\lim_{a\to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{a}
\right)^{a}\right)^{2x}=\left(\lim_{a\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{a}
\right)^{a}\right)^{2x}=e^{2x}.
$$